# How to calculate the ΔT between some dates

Tags: algorithm, date

I need to know the way to calculate the ΔT which is the average time interval between dates

for example:

```
2011-01-18 21:49:36
2011-01-19 20:58:34
2011-01-21 15:31:12
```

These dates give ΔT=1/3 H

How to calculate this value?

I don't need this solution in any language, all I need is the way to get this solution.

Comment: Well, it depends on the language you're using. In Python, you would use `datetime` module, but once again, we can't help you without more information

Comment: If ΔT is the difference between two dates, how is it -1/3 for the three given example dates?

Comment: i have make some clarification if you can help

Answer (score 0):

Given your dates:

```
2011-01-18 21:49:36
2011-01-19 20:58:34
2011-01-21 15:31:12
```

The difference between the first and the second is 23 hours, 8 minutes and 58 seconds, and between the second and the third is 42 hours, 32 minutes and 38 seconds.

**How** can the *"average time interval between dates"* be `1/3 H`?

This doesn't make **any** sense. At all.